# Nested fractions are misaligned in MathJax

Tags: bug, mathjax

In MathJax, it seems that nested fractions have minor problems with alignment. Specifically, they appear further to the right than they should.

It would be interesting to see if this also occurs when a fraction occurs in a sub/superscript, but I couldn't think of a way of actually checking in this scenario whether the gap was larger than it's "supposed" to be.

Consider the code

```
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} \quad \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}$$
```

Here it is *as rendered by the site* (this is not a screenshot):

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} \quad \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}$$

Here it is *as I see it in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

Here it is *as I see it in Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16635* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

Here it is *as I see it when compiling it in my LaTeX editor* (zoomed in 250%):

[image]

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: You can also use: $$\Huge\frac1{\frac1x}$$

Comment: Also, I see the fraction slightly misaligned too; Firefox 23.0.1 on Linux 64bit.

Comment: @Asaf: The reason why I use zoom in bug reports is because (for all we know) the `\Huge` command interacts with the spacing in a way such that `\Huge ...` is not an accurate representation of `...` zoomed up the corresponding amount. In fact, if I were really dedicated to reproducing pixel-for-pixel what I see on my screen, what I would need to do is take a screenshot while using the Windows Magnifier tool...

Comment: For what it's worth, the misalign between my comment and your post is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fractions have a small amount of space added on both sides of them, and it looks like the outer fraction isn't taking that into account when it measures the size of the inner fraction for centering.

I've opened an [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/547) for this on the MathJax site.